# Remote wipe out application in iDevice

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod

How to remote wipe out data/application from iDevice [iPod Touch, iPhone or iPad] ?

Possible solutions are as follow.

1. Configure "Find My iPod" on your iPod
2. Make server call and check is device was reported as stolen ? If yes then call exit(0) function and wipe out data and app.

I used second solution to wipe out data from app. I used following 2 methods for that.

```
-(NSString *)getDatabasePath {
    NSArray *subDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self applicationAppSupportDirectory] error:nil];
    NSString *path = [[[self applicationAppSupportDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[subDir lastObject]]
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xyz.sqlite"];

    return path ;
}
-(void)deleteDatabase {

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager] ;
    NSError *error = nil ;
    NSString *databasePath = [self getDatabasePath];

    if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]) {
        [manager removeItemAtPath:databasePath error:&error] ;
    }
    debug(@"%@",error);

    if (error) {
        [Utility showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Error" andMessage:error.localizedDescription];        
    }
}

-(void)deleteApplication {

    exit(0);
    NSString *appPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] ;
    NSLog(@"%@",appPath);

}
```

I deleted application folder but still Application Logo is there on my iDevice.
Is this a right way to wipe out my app ?
Will apple reject my app for this ?
Why appLogo is still there as i entirely delete app folder ?

Comment: you can't programmatically remove an app, an by the way why you should do this??

Comment: As my app contain sensitive data, client wants to delete that if his device will stolen.

Comment: @milanpanchal: iOS already provides remote wiping capability of the entire device via iCloud and the "Find iPhone" app.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos  - Already, I specified that thing in my question. But for that, user must need to enable that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Apple won't allow you to use exit(0). You can probably wipe the user data though, but you will have make sure the application can still be used after that (I.e. bring the app back into the state of first launch).

For the reporting stolen part: you will have to create your own web UI or similar for this, as Apple currently doesn't allow you to access that kind of iCloud information from within a third party app.